# Vue.js cli insert and show data

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, command-line-interface, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a form, the user insert data and i should show the data in another page just using vue js

I wrote this form

```
<form
              id="main-contact-form"
              class="contact-form row"
              name="contact-form"
              method="post"
            >
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input
                  v-model="this.$store.state.name"
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  class="form-control"
                  required="required"
                  placeholder="اسم المنتج"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input
                  v-model="this.$store.state.price"
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  class="form-control"
                  required="required"
                  placeholder="السعر"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select
                  name="subject"
                  class="form-control"
                  v-model="this.$store.state.sub"
                >
                  <option value="1">اكسسوريز</option>
                  <option value="2">عنايه</option>
                  <option value="3">مكياج</option>
                  <option value="4">شنط</option>
                  <option value="5">عطور</option>
                  <option value="6">اجهزه</option>
                  <option value="7">ملابس نساء</option>
                  <option value="8">رجال</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input
                  :value="img"
                  type="file"
                  name="image"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="اختر صورة المنتج"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <textarea
                  v-model="this.$store.state.message"
                  name="message"
                  id="message"
                  required="required"
                  class="form-control"
                  rows="8"
                  placeholder="وصف المنتج أو نبذة عنه"
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <input
                  @submit.prevent="this.$store.state.add"
                  type="submit"
                  name="submit"
                  class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
                  value="اضافة"
                />
              </div>
            </form>
```

this is my data and function i import them from store

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    name: "",
    price: "",
    sub: "",
    img: "",
    message: "",
    date: "new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString()",
    pro: [],
    add: function () {
      var New = {
        nName: this.name,
        nPrice: this.price,
        nSub: this.sub,
        nImg: this.img,
        nDate: this.date,
      };
      this.name = "";
      this.price = "";
      this.sub = "";
      this.pro.push(New);
      alert(5);
      // this.$router.push("/control-panel");
    },
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

When I press the button, i have this error
( Cannot POST /add-new-product ),
what should i do or what's the wrong with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"add" function should not be at "state" object but moved into "actions"
since it calls (as I can guess) an api to save the object

"generally if you want to modify/mutate your state, you do that in functions declared in mutations:{} and if you make api calls which are asychronous operations you declare functions in actions:{}"

e.x.

```
export default createStore({
  actions:{
     add:function(context,params){
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            //call your api with ajax, assume that it returns correct
            //commit your object to "add" function of mutations
            context.commit('add',params);
        });
     }
  }
})
```

after "add" actions returns successfully from the "api" request then you should have another
"add" function in mutations which will mutate your "pro" attribute of state
and any other "state" attributes/properties
e.x.

```
mutations:{
   add:function(state,obj){
      state.name = "";
      state.price = "";
      state.sub = "";
      state.pro.push(obj);
      alert(5);
    }
}
```

rewrite also your vue "Form" component by adding an "submit" method (which will call the "store action") as follows and move to the "form" tag

```
 <template>
   <form @submit.prevent="submit"
          id="main-contact-form"
          class="contact-form row"
          name="contact-form"
          method="post"
        >
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              v-model="this.$store.state.name"
              type="text"
              name="name"
              class="form-control"
              required="required"
              placeholder="اسم المنتج"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              v-model="this.$store.state.price"
              type="text"
              name="email"
              class="form-control"
              required="required"
              placeholder="السعر"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <select
              name="subject"
              class="form-control"
              v-model="this.$store.state.sub"
            >
              <option value="1">اكسسوريز</option>
              <option value="2">عنايه</option>
              <option value="3">مكياج</option>
              <option value="4">شنط</option>
              <option value="5">عطور</option>
              <option value="6">اجهزه</option>
              <option value="7">ملابس نساء</option>
              <option value="8">رجال</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input
              :value="img"
              type="file"
              name="image"
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="اختر صورة المنتج"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea
              v-model="this.$store.state.message"
              name="message"
              id="message"
              required="required"
              class="form-control"
              rows="8"
              placeholder="وصف المنتج أو نبذة عنه"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input
              
              type="submit"
              name="submit"
              class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
              value="اضافة"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
</template>
<script> 
export default{
   methods:{
      submit:function(){
          this.$store.dispatch("add", {
    nName: this.$store.state.name,
    nPrice: this.$store.state.price,
    nSub: this.$store.state.sub,
    nImg: this.$store.state.img,
    nDate: this.$store.state.date,
  });
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

you can find a working example here

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-d8895